# Ubuntu 14.10 upgrade

Tags: upgrade

I have a Lenovo G510 laptop with a Core i7 processor and 8GB RAM. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, and I want to upgrade to 14.10 without losing my data. How can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)

Comment: Just a small comment: whenever upgrading, backup your essential data to USB or cloud storage or cd/dvd

Answer (score 0):

It is always good practice to back-up your data! I suggest you do that in case anything goes wrong.

1) Open ‘Software & Updates’
2) Select the ‘Updates’ tab
3) Locate section titled ‘Notify me of a new Ubuntu version’
4) In the dropdown menu switch from ‘For long-term support versions‘ to ‘For any new version’
5) open up a terminal by Ctrl+Alt+t and run an update `sudo apt-get update`
Now just give a few minutes and you will be notify that you have an upgrade.

Thanks to OMGUbuntu! http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/10/upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-to-14-10

Cheers,